# Adding a variable to each implode

Tags: php, variables, implode

I have an array of image filenames, which is being passed through a contact form, and being sent as an email to the site owner (these images are uploads, but that part all works fine).

`$Images = $_POST['images6ex']` prints the array, and I'm using `$result = implode(', ', $Images);` to make it more readable.

I'd like to be able to add a base URL to each of the imploded results, so the email recipient can just click (or copy/paste) the link in the email rather than logging into the ftp each time. Is this possible? There's no need to wrap it in a href tag I don't think.

I tried:

```
$fullurl = array($baseurl,$Images);
$result = implode(', ', $fullurl);
```

but I just get

> http://whatever.com/files/, Array

as the output.

My final output needs to be a variable, as this is how the email body is built: http://pastebin.com/JJSW3Jbg. I'm not sure if that's the most effective way to build the email body, but it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest (although not very elegant) solution would probably be:

```
$result = $baseurl.implode(', '.$baseurl, $Images);
```

This prepends every element of `$baseurl` with `$baseurl` except the first one (because that's how `implode` works), and then prepends the entire result with it as well, to fix the first element.

Comment: Thanks - this is spot on and works a treat. It mightn't be the neatest way of doing things, but your answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop to add it to every element in the array, that won't happen just like that. The most elegant method is `array_map`:

```
echo join(', ', array_map(
    function ($url) use ($baseurl) { return "$baseurl/$url"; },
    $Images
));
```